# USB Err1 on Alpine CDA-100

Tags: head-unit

I've been driving the wife's car recently, and her head unit is an Alpine CDA-100. It has a USB connector, which my head unit doesn't, so I thought I'd go ahead and hookup my phone (Android) and blast some tunes.

When I connect the phone via USB, the phone starts charging, so some kind of connection got made. However, the head unit displays "USB Err 1." A quick [Google search](http://www.fixya.com/support/t6151271-just_got_alpine) suggests that the USB port is only for thumb drives, not to play music from your phone. Is that so? The music is stored on the SD card, if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this site](https://itstillruns.com/troubleshoot-alpine-car-radio-6636714.html), "USB Err 1" on Alpine head units indicates that no songs were found on the USB device. Likely, the head unit isn't accessing your phone as a thumb drive, or your phone isn't setting itself up as a thumb drive. Android phones have different options you can configure on how the phone behaves when connected via USB. You want the phone to be setup as "Mass Storage Device." When you connect your phone, it should prompt you for which mode you want to use.

Comment: Also if you own a IOS device it may ask you to allow access to the phone. But only if the headunit actually supports IOS devices.